# Tradução Sinalizações Rejeitada

Tags: bug, tradução, internacionalização

O resumo da rejeição não está traduzido. Não sei se há outro que possa estar também por traduzir

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já agora tem também um "by" em vez de por: "respondidas 2/07 às 13:16 by"